# replace specefique codes in a script using through a tool

Tags: batch-file, notepad++

I have a script that contain random codes but I am searching for a way in notepad ++ or for a batch-file or any tool that can replace sepcifque codes, here is an example:

```
Random
If this equal that then you soulAd do this and do that therefore..
the code should be executed immediatly
--stackb

select * from user_error where object_name = name
select * from user_error where table= randomly

case 1 a = b else c=a
--stacke
Begin with the structure of the data and divide the codes
end with what you know
```

I want to replace the words between the comments stack b and stack a so the result will be like below

```
Random
If this equal that then you sould do this and do that therefore..
the code should be executed immediatly
--stackb

The codes here has been replaced,
can you do that ?

case 1 a = b else c=a
--stacke
Begin with the structure of the data and divide the codes
end with what you know
```

Is there a code in batch file or note pad ++ where I can acheive my result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++, go to `Search > Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what (see below for explanation):

   ```
   (\-\-stackb.*?)select.+?$\r?\nselect.+?$(\r?\n.*?\-\-stacke)
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   $1replaced text$2
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression" & select checkbox ". matches newline"
4. Then press `Replace All`.

This will transform the following file:

```
Random
If this equal that then you soulAd do this and do that therefore..
the code should be executed immediatly
--stackb

select * from user_error where object_name = name
select * from user_error where table= randomly

case 1 a = b else c=a
--stacke
Begin with the structure of the data and divide the codes
end with what you know
```

To:

```
Random
If this equal that then you soulAd do this and do that therefore..
the code should be executed immediatly
--stackb

replaced text

case 1 a = b else c=a
--stacke
Begin with the structure of the data and divide the codes
end with what you know
```

Regex explanation:

- **`\-\-stackb`** matches the string `--stackb`. Nothing special here, except of the backslashes which *escapes* special characters. This means that `-` will be interpreted as a literal `-` and not as a regex special character
- **`.*?`** the dot `.` matches *any character*, plus the newline since we activated the option ". matches newline". The asterisk `*` is a *quantifier* for *matching 0 or more times*. So `.*` means match any character or newlines 0 or more times. When a quantifier is followed by a questionmark `?` it makes the quantifier *non-greedy*, which is a more advanced topic but in simple words it's like saying to the quantifier *try to satisfy yourself with the possible minimum quantity of `.`*
- **`(\-\-stackb.*?)`** now that you have understood the meaning of the regex, you can add a parenthesis in order to capture the matching result. You can access the result using the special variable `$1` (or `\1` it's the same). We are using it in the replacement as you can see.
- **`select.+?$\r?\n`** the only new stuff here, is the `$` which matches the *end of line* and the special characters `\r` (carriage return), `\n` (newline) which are used to find a line break. Note that `\r` is followed by the `?` quantifier which means *match 1 or 0 times*.

Comment: nice but can you explain what does the code means ? so i can knwo how to use it (\-\-stackb.*?)select.+?$\r?\nselect.+?$(\r?\n.*?\-\-stacke) what does *?$ means ? .. and can I replace a large script ?

Comment: I've just edited the answer with explanation. I hope this helps. But to be honest the best thing in your case is to read first a simple [regex tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+tutorial)

Comment: psxls thanx for your explantion , but in your code I have to include the first worf in every line, If i have a large paragraph how do I replace that .? your code will be usefull ?

Comment: The regex I wrote was to suit your specific example. If you want to remove any kind of text around `--stackb` and `--stacke` then use the following: find=`(\-\-stackb).+?(\-\-stacke)`, replace=`$1\n\nreplaced\n\n$2`.